# *Highchart* Color of chart change when downloading two time continuously

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart and when I download the image, it shows like in the left picture, and when I download it for the second time, it shows like in the right picture.

[image]

As you can see that when I downloaded the picture for the second time, the color of the columns are changed. How can I advoid this changing ?.

here is my jsFiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/2mvuLLs9/27/)         . Sometime it happens, sometime not, and I think the problem comes from the zooming function that I used, after zooming and then when I download the graph, the color will be changed

Comment: Please recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/2mvuLLs9/11/. Sometime it happens, sometime not, and I think the problem comes from the zooming function that I used, after zooming and then when I download the graph, the color will be changed

Comment: We need to stable steps and demo whcih introduce that issue.

Comment: sorry I put the wrong file, this is the correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/2mvuLLs9/27/

Comment: Remove this line: this.series[0].update({}); from your afterSetExtremes event.

Comment: this line is used to update my values which displayed in the legend, because everytime when we zooming, this total values will be changed also

Comment: Instaed of that, better is manipulate on SVG elements, directly. Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/84wkk6ef/

Comment: that problem is solved now, thank you Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line: this.series[0].update({}); from your afterSetExtremes event and then use attr() function to manipulate on SVG elements, directly.

```
events: {
            afterSetExtremes: function () {
                var sum = 0;
                min = parseFloat(this.getExtremes().min);
                max = parseFloat(this.getExtremes().max);
                Highcharts.each(this.series, function (p, i) {
                    sum = 0;
                    Highcharts.each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
                        if (min <= ob.x && ob.x <= max) {
                            sum += ob.y;
                        }
                    });
                    p.legendItem.attr({
                        text: p.name + ' (Gesamt: ' + sum + ')'
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/84wkk6ef/